# Link existing Google Analytics data for OLDPAGENAME.html to track and display data for NEWPAGENAME.PHP

Tags: google-analytics

I am revising a site and some changes to page naming will be unavoidable. I would like to retain a relationship to the historical Google Analytics information for pages whose names will be changed.

When changing page names and extensions -- including changes that reorder folder structure -- how can I link the Google Analytics data for NEWPAGENAME.php, for example, to the data associated with the OLDPAGENAME.html page it has replaced?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match the data once they have been acquired in Google Analytics, so one possibility is to apply a filter that rewrites the names of the pages and transforms them into the original ones, eg: index.html -> index.php (does not reflect the reality but ensures that the data is comparable and aggregable).